# Statisitcs about ios devices and language

Tags: ios, localization

A want to localize one of my iOS apps into Chinese. I notice iOS has "simplified chinese", "traditional chinese" and "traditional chinese (hong kong)" as language choices in the settings.

To decide what language to go for, I am looking for statistics such as % of ios devices configured in a certain language (not just Chinese but splitted up into the above 3 variants). Been searching the web but can't find such info. Where can this info be found?

Comment: Probably shouldn't be on StackOverflow...

Comment: Any suggestions where it could be posted then?

Comment: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/